# Unit testing AccountController from default ASP.Net MVC 4 Application project

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I'm working on MVC4 application and interested in creating a set of controller unit tests. All my attempts to unit test methods from AccountController end up with the same exception related to `WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity:`

**To call this method, the "Membership.Provider" property must be an instance of "ExtendedMembershipProvider".**

I'm using `SimpleMemebership` provider that is being initialized through `InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute`

Can someone provide guidance how to do this properly?

Comment: did you define your membership provider in your app.config of your test project?

Comment: bas, can you elaborate on "define"? I use default implemtation in my web project. membership provider is initialized using InitializeSimpleMembership attribute. Everything works perfect, except I'm unable unit test Account controller.

Answer (score 1):

I'll drop it as answer since this will become painfully ugly in a comment. What I did, is add a membershipprovider in my test project. I have a custom membership provider, but in your case the app.config would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider"
             type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

You probably get complaints about a missing reference of WebMatrix. Add the following references:

- WebMatrix.Data
- WebMatrix.WebData

Set copy to local to `true`.

Then make sure you call the `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection` and you're good to go.

Hope this helps.

Comment: alternatively you could just wrap the membership provider, and lazy load it so that you can mock it in your unit tests. not sure what you are trying to achieve, but the membership thingy might be something you want to exclude in your unit tests.

Comment: I think you suggestion regarding "but the membership thingy might be something you want to exclude in your unit tests" is great, but it's the purpose of my unit test :).
Anyways, you suggestion to include SimpleMenbership config worked to a point where it fails now inside WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.Login():

System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(String userName, Boolean createPersistentCookie, String strCookiePath)

Comment: you run into a specific exception?